# IPA convert to English text

Tags: ipa

mænɪdʒ                                      tʃaɪld
rɪzʌlt                                      pælɪs
sku:l                                       prəvaɪd
detə                                        sʒ:fɪs
kənfʒ: m                                    j u:ʒl
eɪnʃənt                                     dʒʒ: nl

what are their English text in represent of IPA?

Comment: Looks like an excercise. Solve it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You probably copied your IPA symbols wrong. 
If you want a good answer, edit your question with the correct version of your symbols - e.g. you're merging 2 sounds, your representation of the central vowel (schwa) is /ʒ/, that's wrong, it should be /ə/ - but not in all positions.

However, I was able to "decode" most of it:

manage child
result palace
school provide debtor surface confirm usual (?) ancient jurnal